# Symmetric operator is not self-adjoint operator.

Tags: operator-algebras

Could you please give me example of operator which is symmetric but not self-adjoint? (i know, that if is self-adjoint it implies that is symetric)

Comment: You can see an example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator#Boundary_conditions).